# Observing changes only within a window that commits successfully

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, reactiveui

Suppose I have the following class:

```
public class Person : ReactiveObject, IEditableObject
{
    private string name;
    private string nameCopy;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return this.name; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref this.name, value); }
    }

    public void BeginEdit()
    {
        this.nameCopy = this.name;
    }

    public void CancelEdit()
    {
        this.name = this.nameCopy;
    }

    public void EndEdit()
    {
    }
}
```

Now suppose I want to create an observable sequence (of `Unit`) that "ticks" whenever a change is *committed* to `Name`. That is, I only care about changes to `Name` that occur between a call to `BeginEdit` and and a subsequent call to `EndEdit`. Any changes prior to a call to `CancelEdit` should be ignored and the sequence should not tick.

I'm struggling to get my head around how I would do this with Rx. It seems I would need state in the pipeline somewhere in order to know whether the change occurred during the window of `BeginEdit`/`EndEdit` calls. I suppose I could timestamp everything and compare timestamps, but that seems a nasty hack.

I came pretty close using a dedicated `Subject` for edit actions along with `Observable.Merge`:

```
public class Person : ReactiveObject, IEditableObject
{
    private readonly Subject<EditAction> editActions;
    private readonly IObservable<Unit> changedDuringEdit;
    private string name;
    private string nameCopy;

    public Person()
    {
        this.editActions = new Subject<EditAction>();

        var nameChanged = this.ObservableForProperty(x => x.Name).Select(x => x.Value);
        var editBeginning = this.editActions.Where(x => x == EditAction.Begin);
        var editCommitted = this.editActions.Where(x => x == EditAction.End);

        this.changedDuringEdit = nameChanged
            .Buffer(editBeginning, _ => editCommitted)
            .Where(x => x.Count > 0)
            .Select(_ => Unit.Default);
    }

    public IObservable<Unit> ChangedDuringEdit
    {
        get { return this.changedDuringEdit; }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return this.name; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref this.name, value); }
    }

    public void BeginEdit()
    {
        this.editActions.OnNext(EditAction.Begin);
        this.nameCopy = this.name;
    }

    public void CancelEdit()
    {
        this.editActions.OnNext(EditAction.Cancel);
        this.Name = this.nameCopy;
    }

    public void EndEdit()
    {
        this.editActions.OnNext(EditAction.End);
    }

    private enum EditAction
    {
        Begin,
        Cancel,
        End
    }
}
```

However, if several changes are cancelled, and then one is committed, the observable ticks several times on commit (once for each prior cancellation, and once again for the commit). Not to mention the fact that I get a `List<Unit>` which I don't actually need. In a way, this would still satisfy my use case, but not my curiosity or sense of code aesthetic.

I feel like `Join` should solve this fairly elegantly:

```
var nameChanged = this.ObservableForProperty(x => x.Name).Select(_ => Unit.Default);
var editBeginning = this.editActions.Where(x => x == EditAction.Begin);
var editCommitted = this.editActions.Where(x => x == EditAction.End);
var editCancelled = this.editActions.Where(x => x == EditAction.Cancel);
var editCancelledOrCommitted = editCancelled.Merge(editCommitted);

this.changedDuringEdit = editBeginning
    .Join(nameChanged, _ => editCancelledOrCommitted, _ => editCancelledOrCommitted, (editAction, _) => editAction == EditAction.End)
    .Where(x => x)
    .Select(_ => Unit.Default);
```

But this doesn't work either. It seems `Join` is not subscribing to `editCancelledOrCommitted`, for reasons I don't understand.

Anyone have any ideas how to go about this cleanly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
IObservable<Unit> beginEditSignal = ...;
IObservable<Unit> commitSignal = ...;
IObservable<Unit> cancelEditSignal = ...;
IObservable<T> propertyChanges = ...;


// this will yield an array after each commit
// that has all of the changes for that commit.
// nothing will be yielded if the commit is canceled
// or if the changes occur before BeginEdit.
IObservable<T[]> commitedChanges = beginEditSignal
    .Take(1)
    .SelectMany(_ => propertyChanges
        .TakeUntil(commitSignal)
        .ToArray()
        .Where(changeList => changeList.Length > 0)
        .TakeUntil(cancelEditSignal))
    .Repeat();


// if you really only want a `Unit` when something happens
IObservable<Unit> changeCommittedSignal = beginEditSignal
     .Take(1)
     .SelectMany(_ => propertyChanges
         .TakeUntil(commitSignal)
         .Count()
         .Where(c => c > 0)
         .Select(c => Unit.Default)
         .TakeUntil(cancelEditSignal))
     .Repeat();
```

Comment: Nice Brandon. That is something like what I thought _you_ would want: each of the changes that happens during an 'edit' pushed to you once it is committed. However it appears that Kent just want's a `Unit`, not sure why.

Comment: @LeeCampbell Yeah I'm a bit confused by that as well.  I'll add a variation that does that.

Comment: Yeah, I just wanted a unit to signal that a change has occurred - I don't care specifically what changed, nor how many properties changed during the edit. In reality, my view model represents configuration and another view model needs to refresh itself from the config whenever any change is committed. I'm looking forward to trying this out. Will post again later when I've done so. Thanks.

Comment: This works! I will now proceed to stare at it until it makes sense to me...Actually, the only part I'm struggling to grasp is the `TakeUntil(cancelEditSignal)` bit. I read it as never getting there because of the prior `TakeUntil(commitSignal)`, but I'm obviously reading it wrong because I see an important difference in behavior if I remove the second `TakeUntil` call.

Comment: Frigging **LIGHT BULB!!** Got it! The thing that made this click for me was to think of *pulling* items from the end of the pipeline rather than thinking about pushing items into the pipeline and trying to trace through what happens to them. This made it obvious to me that a cancellation signal will result in the inner pipeline selecting nothing, whereas a commit signal will allow the count of changes to propagate through to the `Where` and `Select`. Thanks very much - this is exactly the kind of elegant solution I was after.

Answer (score 1):

You have a timing problem that I don't think you have articulated yet; when are you hoping for the changes to tick?

1. either as they occur
2. once the commit happens

The clear and obvious problem with 1) is that you don't know if the changes will be committed, so why would you raise them. IMO, this only leaves option 2). If the change is cancelled, then no event is raised.

Next question I have is, do you want each change raised? ie. for the process

```
[Begin]-->[Name="fred"]-->[Name="bob"]-->[Commit]
```

Should this raise 1 or 2 events when the Commit is made? As you are only pushing the token type `Unit`, it seems redundant to push two values. This now leads me to think that you just want to push a `Unit` value when `EndEdit()` is executed and the values have changed.

This leaves us with a painfully simple implementation:

```
public class Person : ReactiveObject, IEditableObject
{
    private readonly ISubject<Unit> changedDuringEdit = new Subject<Unit>();
    private string name;
    private string nameCopy;


    public string Name
    {
        get { return this.name; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref this.name, value); }
    }

    public void BeginEdit()
    {
        this.nameCopy = this.name;
    }

    public void CancelEdit()
    {
        this.name = this.nameCopy;
    }

    public void EndEdit()
    {
        if(!string.Equals(this.nameCopy, this.name))
        {
            changedDuringEdit.OnNext(Unit.Default);
        }
    }

    public IObservable<Unit> ChangedDuringEdit
    {
        get { return this.changedDuringEdit.AsObservable(); }
    }
}
```

Is this what you are looking for? If not can you help me understand the complexities I am missing? If it is then I would be keen to flesh this out so that I wasn't recommending using `Subject`s :-)

Comment: Thanks Lee. You've inferred my requirements correctly: tick only on commit, and preferably only once to indicate things have changed. However, my example was simplified: I have a lot more than one property that can change. Hence, I wanted to leverage the existing observables I have and somehow tie them together to get an observable that ticks once on a commit that includes a change to any property.

Comment: Please have an upvote, in part for your useful response, and in part for being the guy whose [fantastic book](http://www.introtorx.com/) got me halfway competent in Rx. Cheers!